# Why is the value of the print statement not actually printing . . . no error code for syntax is showing up

Tags: python

I made a function to get the cheapest shipping method and from what I can tell my code looks correct, but the value is not printing and there is no error code.

If thought it may have something to do when indentation, but that doesn't seem to correct it

```
 def cheapest_shipping_method(weight):

  ground = ground_shipping(weight)
  premium = premium_ground_shipping
  drone = drone_shipping_costs(weight)

  if ground < premium and ground < drone:
    method = "standard ground"
    cost = ground
  elif premium < ground and premium < drone:
    method = "premium ground"
    cost = premium
  else: 
    method = "drone shipping"
    cost = drone

  print(
    "The cheapest option is $%.2f with %s shipping."
      % (cost, method)
   )

  print_cheapest_shipping_method(4.8)
  print_cheapest_shipping_method(41.5)
```

Expected to see the cheapest option for shipping with the listed values (4.8 & 41.5).

Comment: You don't call `cheapest_shipping_method`. It seems you call `print_cheapest_shipping_method` inside `cheapest_shipping_method`, but that function is not provided anywhere.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your core `cheapest_shipping_method` method seems fine.  I didn't have to change it at all to get reasonable results.  Guessing at what you mean to be doing here, and adding missing functions and values arbitrarily, this runs and prints different values for your two inputs:

```
def ground_shipping(weight):
    return 2 * weight

premium_ground_shipping = 11.5

def drone_shipping_costs(weight):
    return 10 * weight

def cheapest_shipping_method(weight):

  ground = ground_shipping(weight)
  premium = premium_ground_shipping
  drone = drone_shipping_costs(weight)

  if ground < premium and ground < drone:
    method = "standard ground"
    cost = ground
  elif premium < ground and premium < drone:
    method = "premium ground"
    cost = premium
  else:
    method = "drone shipping"
    cost = drone

  print(
    "The cheapest option is $%.2f with %s shipping."
      % (cost, method)
   )

cheapest_shipping_method(4.8)
cheapest_shipping_method(41.5)
```

Result:

```
The cheapest option is $9.60 with standard ground shipping.
The cheapest option is $11.50 with premium ground shipping.
```

So you just needed to move your calls to your function outside of the function and make the names match.